# Observing scroll position with requestAnimationFrame in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently im trying to implement `requestAnimationFrame()` in my code.  My goal is to observe the current scrollPosition of the window and update a variable constantly.

Code of my Vue Single File Component:

```
<script>
   data() {
      return {
         scrollPosition: 0
      }
   },
   methods: {
      updateScrollPosition() {
         this.scrollPosition = window.scrollY
         window.requestAnimationFrame(this.updateScrollPosition())
      }
   },
   created() {
      this.updateScrollPosition()
   }
</script>
```

https://jsbin.com/gizamohuxu/edit?html,js,console,output

I expected that the scrollPosition constanstly changes based on the actual window scroll position. But actually I get `InternalError: "too much recursion"`. So basically I feel like I didnt really understood this `requestAnimationFrame()` function — need help. Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: so its not possible with `requestAnimationFrame()` ?

Comment: probably it is, but this is native api for scroll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You directly call `updateScrollPosition()` in your statement and pass the result to `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(this.updateScrollPosition());
```

You need to pass the function directly to [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), e.g.:

```
// pass function to requestAnimationFrame
window.requestAnimationFrame(this.updateScrollPosition);
```

Then it'll work as expected.

Altough you should use the [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) event if you want to get notified when the user scrolls, you can subscribe to it via [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      scrollPosition: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateScrollPosition() {
      this.scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.updateScrollPosition);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    // remove listener again
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.updateScrollPosition);
  }
});
```

Also remember to clean up the registered listener with [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) once you don't need it anymore.

Comment: thank you. feeling lil bit dumb that this was the error — lol.

Comment: @Karl np, glad I could help 

Answer (score 2):

<s>I believe implementing this using `requestAnimationFrame` would actually be worse for browser performance.</s>

## Important

The above statement is incorrect. You can use `requestAnimationFrame` to throttle the scroll event to make it more efficient as seen on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event).

You essentially created infinite loop and that's why the call stack was exceeded. I would listen to the `scroll` event using `addEventListener` on `window`.

## Example

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    scrollPosition: 0,
    ticking: false
  },
  methods: {
     updateScrollPosition() {
       this.scrollPosition = window.scrollY;   
       
       if (!this.ticking) {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          
          // do something

          this.ticking = false;
        });

          this.ticking = true;
      }
     }
  },
  created() {    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.updateScrollPosition);
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  {{ scrollPosition }}
</div>
  <div>scroll</div>
  <div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div><div>scroll</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but what is the error in my code? Is it really impossible to observe the scroll position in such way? 

This article suggests that requestAnimationFrame() is more performant than other solutions https://ehsangazar.com/optimizing-javascript-event-listeners-for-performance-e28406ad406c

Comment: @Karl sorry I've updated answer. I miss understood your request. I've added example of using requestAnimation from to throttle scroll event. It's using your code